# apache ignite - How to deploy cache to some certain cluster group

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, ignite

For apache ignite, can I deploy cache to some certain cluster group?
If can, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define node filter for cache configuration using `CacheConfiguration.setNodeFilter(IgnitePredicate<ClusterNode> nodeFilter)` method.

Cache will be started on node if `ClusterNode` instance passed filter represented by `IgnitePredicate<ClusterNode>`. You can filter node by node's attributes (defined statically) or by any other node properties.